# GitHub Pull Request Builder not triggering Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins

I have followed https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/ and created Jenkins job. I created Gitwebhook http://:/ghprbhook/. Selected the “Let me select individual events” option and selected just the “Pull requests” option. I can see green tick in for that hook. Selected Github project option and entered the Github repo URL for which I want the PR builds without .git extension.Selected Git SCM.Added GitHub "Repository URL".Under Advanced, set "refspec" to +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*. In "Branch Specifier", entered ${sha1}. Under "Build Triggers", checked "Github pull requests builder". Added myself as admin.Checked "Use github hooks for build triggering". But If I create a PR it does not trigger this job. Please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps and try this, it would work for you.

- Repository URL = `Paste your repository URL`
- Credential = `select your credential`

*Click Advanced Section*

- Name = put `origin`
- Refspec =  put `+refs/pull/${ghprbPullId}/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/${ghprbPullId}/*`

  *Branches to build*
- put `${ghprbActualCommit}`

[image]

**Under `Build Triggers`**

- check "Github pull requests builder"

  - Select your GitHub API credentials
  - check `Use github hooks for build triggering`
  - check `Build every pull request automatically without asking (Dangerous!)`

Thanks

Comment: check Build every pull request automatically without asking (Dangerous!), solved the issue